# Fundamental Group of a free G-space

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, equivariant-topology

It is very well known that any group $H$ can be the fundamental group of a topological space. What happened if we restrict the class of topological spaces to the free equivariant topological spaces? More precisely, for a fixed finite group $G$  what groups $H$ can be the fundamental group of a free finite $G$-simplicial complex?

Comment: For someone who's only been half awake, what exactly is the fundamental group of a $G$-simplicial complex?

Comment: It is just the usual fundamental group for topological spaces. In order to avoid any confusion,  I should assume from the first place that I am interested in connected G-simplicial complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EG$ is the contractible, free G-space. Given any space $X$ we may take the product $EG \times X$ to be a G-space by acting on $EG$. This then a free G-space which is homotopy equivalent to $X$. Hence, any fundamental group is realized by a free G-space.

This is the cofibrant replacement of the G-space $X$ with the trivial action, in G-spaces (where a map is a weak equivalence if it is equivariant and the underlying map is a weak equivalence).

Edit: To answer your actual question: all finitely presented groups (as is the case for the nonequivariant case). We can follow the same method described above by taking the product of a finite CW complex with fundamental group $G$ and crossing with a free G-space with a trivial fundamental group.

To construct such a (connected) G-space, start with a copy of G and add segments between any two elements of the group. This has an obvious group action by sending the segment from a to b to the segment from $ga$ to $gb$. Then pick any loop represented by a sequence of edges and attach a disk along this loop. Just as before this has an obvious action by sending the disk attached to $a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots a_n$ to $ga_1 ga_2 ga_3 \dots ga_n$.

Since we killed a generating set of loops, we have constructed a space with trivial $\pi_1$. Similar constructions can be done for any homotopy group.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But, the problem is that this space does not have a structure of a finite simplicial complex

Comment: @MathFun Sorry, I've now answered your question.

Comment: If you know a little about the theory of G-spaces this construction should not be surprising. If you know that an $EG$ exists, it can be cofibrantly replaced. In this category, the cofibrant replacement is a free G-CW complex. The skeletons of free G-CW complexes are free G-CW complexes, so we may just take its 2-skeleton to find such an example. You'll note that if you proceed to kill all the homotopy groups of our space $X$, we have found an $EG$ with $X$ as the 2-skeleton.

Comment: @ConnerMillan, about your previous comment. You are right we can be procced like that, but there is still some problem with this method, please note the second skeleton of $EG$ is not finite CW-complex,i.e, it has a countably infinite number of points and edges.

Comment: @ConnerMillan, I think in your answer you meant that we need to find a two finite simplicial complex X and Y which $\pi_1(X)=0$ and $\pi_1(Y)=H$ and moreover X admits a free G-action. Then, $X\times Y$ presents satisfying the desired property. For this purpose, it is enough to put $X=G\ast G\ast G$ and the construction of Y is also very well known... Again, thank you very much for your help.